# Project binding redirects succeed as console application but fail as class library

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, google-calendar-api, app-config, nuget-package

I recently upgraded from Visual Studio 2010 to Visual Studio 2012.  One of my projects that was good in VS 2010 now fails to compile in VS 2012 with binding errors.  The project is a Class Library with an app.config containing the proper binding redirects.  The strange thing is if I switch the project to a Console Application, everything binds and compiles just fine.  Switch it back to Class Library and it fails again.

What is different about binding redirects between a Class Library and a Console Application that would cause this behavior at compile time?

Here is a sample error from the Build Output:

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1605,5): warning MSB3268: The primary reference "Google.Apis.Auth" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the framework assembly "System.Runtime, Version=1.5.11.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which could not be resolved in the currently targeted framework. ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0". To resolve this problem, either remove the reference "Google.Apis.Auth" or retarget your application to a framework version which contains "System.Runtime, Version=1.5.11.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".

Here are the binding redirects from the project's app.config file:

```
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.2.18.0" newVersion="2.2.18.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="log4net" publicKeyToken="669e0ddf0bb1aa2a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.2.13.0" newVersion="1.2.13.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Threading.Tasks" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.6.6.0" newVersion="2.6.6.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.6.6.0" newVersion="2.6.6.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.Desktop" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.0.165.0" newVersion="1.0.165.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Primitives" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.2.18.0" newVersion="2.2.18.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

I understand needing the redirects in the entry app config file at run time.  What to do about compile time?

Comment: I know a little more.  Before the update to VS2012, VS2010 did not need binding redirects at compile time.  After the update, both VS2010 and VS2012 bindings fail at compile time unless the binding redirects are in an app.config for a console application.  What did the VS2012 install do that broke VS2010?

Comment: These bindingRedirects can only have an affect at runtime, they are not used at build time.  You didn't say enough about where you got this Google assembly.

Comment: Hans you are on target.  I don't know why they solve the compile time issue if it's a console application but they do - a curiosity.  I finally solved this by updating my NuGet package manger (update failed, had to uninstall then reinstall), then by using it to remove and add back the packages to the problem project.